# JPA / Eclipselink @Cache expiry ignored

Tags: java, caching, jpa, eclipselink

I'm currently evaluating JPA/Eclipselink as an alternative to our current very ugly jdbc database access. The situation is the following:

Multiple clients access the same database and sometimes edit the same data. This data should be refreshed regularly and only be cached for a short period of time. From my understanding the @Cache annotation should exactly do that.

The following code is based on the jpa/eclipselink on [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html)

```
@Entity
@Cache(expiry = 100)
public class Todo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String summary;
    private String description;
... getter/setter/toString omited
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        EntityManagerFactory factory =
                Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mysql");
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

        TypedQuery<Todo> q = em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM Todo t", Todo.class);

        List<Todo> todoList = q.getResultList();
        System.out.println("Query 1 read");
        for (int i = 0; i < todoList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("1: " + todoList.get(i));
        }

        Thread.sleep(30000);

        TypedQuery<Todo> q2 =
                em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM Todo t", Todo.class);
        // q2.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.storeMode", "REFRESH");

        List<Todo> todoList2 = q2.getResultList();
        System.out.println("Query 2 read");

        for (int i = 0; i < todoList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("1: " + todoList.get(i));
            System.out.println("2: " + todoList2.get(i));
            System.out.println(todoList.get(i) == todoList2.get(i));
        }
    }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">


    <persistence-unit name="mysql" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.logging.level" value="ALL" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Running the Programm produces the following output:

```
...
[EL Finest]: query: 2013-06-19 14:30:55.897--UnitOfWork(31211079)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Todo sql="SELECT ID, DESCRIPTION, SUMMARY FROM TODO")
[EL Finest]: connection: 2013-06-19 14:30:55.907--ServerSession(7427424)--Connection(7633596)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-06-19 14:30:55.907--ServerSession(7427424)--Connection(7633596)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT ID, DESCRIPTION, SUMMARY FROM TODO
[EL Finest]: connection: 2013-06-19 14:30:55.924--ServerSession(7427424)--Connection(7633596)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [default].
Query 1 read
1: Todo [id=1, summary=s1, description=d1]
1: Todo [id=2, summary=qwet, description=d2]
[EL Finest]: query: 2013-06-19 14:31:25.932--UnitOfWork(31211079)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Todo sql="SELECT ID, DESCRIPTION, SUMMARY FROM TODO")
[EL Finest]: connection: 2013-06-19 14:31:25.932--ServerSession(7427424)--Connection(7633596)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
[EL Fine]: sql: 2013-06-19 14:31:25.932--ServerSession(7427424)--Connection(7633596)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT ID, DESCRIPTION, SUMMARY FROM TODO
[EL Finest]: connection: 2013-06-19 14:31:25.934--ServerSession(7427424)--Connection(7633596)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [default].
Query 2 read
1: Todo [id=1, summary=s1, description=d1]
2: Todo [id=1, summary=s1, description=d1]
true
1: Todo [id=2, summary=qwet, description=d2]
2: Todo [id=2, summary=qwet, description=d2]
true
```

While the Thread sleeps I change a value in the database. I would expect to get the new value from the database, because the value in the cache should have been expired. It seems the code simply ignores the @Cache annotation. I also tried various other settings like type=CacheType.NONE und alwaysRefresh=true, but none did change anything.

When I add the storeMode-QueryHint, the query always refreshes the result. This is not exactly what I want and it seems I need to add it to each query which is quite error prone. But it is still strange that the Cache annotation is ignored.

I also tried to use a DescriptorCustomizer, but it also has no effect, despite being used (tested with a breakpoint).

```
public void customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) {
        descriptor.alwaysRefreshCache();
        descriptor.alwaysRefreshCacheOnRemote();
        descriptor.disableCacheHits();
        descriptor.disableCacheHitsOnRemote();
    }
```

Update:

Some words to the system I'm developing. It's module to read/write our master data. Therefore, it feels wrong to have, for example, an User-object twice in memory for the same user. Also after I tested the @ReadOnly annotation I noticed that the isolation-parameter of the @Cache annotation seems to work, but still nothing about the expire, alwaysrefresh, etc.

Comment: You are using the same EntityManager instance.  The cache settings apply to the shared cache, while the EntityManager is required to keep the same object in memory until it is closed or cleared - otherwise a simple find operation might wipe out changes in a running transaction.  Get a new EntityManager or clear the existing one before the Thread.sleep call

Comment: But I want the existing objects to be refreshed. Also when I detach the objects or clear the em after the first db read, I get new objects. Having the same database row with two different states in the application at the same time is not a very pleasent thought. 
Mainly I want it to be refreshed everytime (or preferable after a timeout) I access the database.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same EntityManager instance. The cache settings apply to the shared cache, while the EntityManager is required to keep the same object in memory until it is closed or cleared - otherwise a simple find operation might wipe out changes in a running transaction. Get a new EntityManager or clear the existing one will cause the EntityManager to go to the shared cache and/or the database as necessary.

If you do need the object refreshed in the current EM context, you will have to explicitly call em.refresh or use a query hint so that it knows to wipe out any existing changes with what is in the database.

Each EM represents a transactional context, and since each thread should have its own EntityManager, there will already be multiple copies of your entity in the application.  You will run into trouble if you rely on a particular instance read from an EntityManager always reflecting the current changes - it can only really reflect what is in the database at the moment it was read.  This is why it is important to merge in changes when necessary, and is probably not a good idea to cache objects in the application - access them from EntityManagers as needed instead.

ut if you want the object and are not making changes, mark it as read-only which will pull it from the shared cache instead of the EM, and so reflect the cache settings: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/Shared_and_Isolated#Read-Only_Entities .  If the entity is cached in the shared cache, this will be the instance you get back, and all EMs will return the same object instance - it is up to your app to manage concurrency issues on the entity itself.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm starting to grasp the whole problem of the situation. I can't set the entities "read-only" because in rare cases I need to write them.
The current situation is that I create a module to read/write our master data. While it is not critical I would like to reduce the memory footprint by only holding objects once.
But it still doesn't expain why the @Cache annotation isn't working. This is also where I would define if the entity is shared or isolated.

Comment: The @Cache annotion is likely working, it just doesn't apply to your EM.  It is a common design flaw for users to hold onto an EM and make it long lived as they seem to have been designed to be short term light weight sessions.  The entities read in can only represent the data at the point the entity was loaded.  After that, the EM gives you consistently the same data unless you explicitly refresh it, or clear the em.  This allows the app to make calculations and changes without worry that the data is changing underneath - it can use optimistic locking to ensure it will not write stale data.

Comment: But than what exactly is the @Cache annotation doing? Also it seems that every EM uses its own Database connection which makes it quite expensive to create and tear it down.
What really annoys me about jpa/eclipselink is that there is documentation, but when I copy an example it just doesn't work and I get no errors. Having a similar problem with lazy loading right now. Eclipselink just ignores the Annotation and does eager-loading. No error, warning or what so ever.
Is there any good introduction to JPA's persistence strategy. Maybe I'm missing some basics ...

Comment: Lazy of 1:1 and basics requires weaving, so check you have it setup or are in a container where weaving is enabled by default - http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving  The cache annotation is for the shared cache, and EclipseLink caching is described here http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Caching   if you have problems, by all means, post them here or on EclipseLink's forum to get help or pointers.  Good examples can be found all over, I reference http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA mostly

Comment: Connections should be pooled, so I don't see how they are any more expensive to set up or tear down.  Once the EM is done with it, it returns it to the pool.  It only reuses the same connection if it is in a transaction - which are expensive.  The EM itself isn't.  Don't wrap them in transactions unless you have changes you need to make, and even then, transactions can be obtained only when the changes are ready.